# Where did flour come from in the midbar?

Tags: dor-hamidbar, mincha-meal-offering

I was thinking about what bedikas chametz in the midbar might have looked like, but then realized that they probably didn’t have any chametz at all, with the maan being their sustenance.

However if so, where did they get the flour that was needed for the meal offerings in the Mishkan?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it came from the heavens as the Gemera in Menachot 69b says:

בעי ר' זירא חיטין שירדו בעבים מהו למאי אי למנחות אמאי לא אלא לשתי הלחם מאי

"Rabbi Zeira raises a dilemma: With regard to wheat that fell from the clouds, what is the halakha?" (look at Tosfoat here who quotes Senhedrin 59b that meat also fell from shamyim)

*Another answer (that I don't have a source for) is that they could have traded for it along the way.

Answer (score 0):

The wilderness surrounding the camp was essentially transformed into an oasis. While wheat is not explicitly mentioned, the miraculous water from the well of Miriam made it possible for wheat to grow.

[Legends of the Jews 3:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Legends_of_the_Jews.3.1.112?lang=bi)

> The different parts of the camp were separated by these rivers, so
> that women, visiting each other, were obliged to make use of ships.
> Then the water discharged itself beyond the encampment, where it
> surrounded a great plain, in which grew every conceivable kind of
> plant and tree; and these trees, owing to the miraculous water, daily
> bore fresh fruits. This well brought fragrant herbs with it, so that
> the women had no need of perfumes on the march, for the herbs they
> gathered served this purpose. This well furthermore threw down soft,
> fragrant kinds of grass that served as pleasant couches for the poor,
> who had no pillows or bedclothes.